# Running into input/output error when saving tensorflow session checkpoint (on google colab)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

First off, here is the error:

```
UnknownError (see above for traceback): drive/Colab Notebooks/saved_model/model1.ckpt-313.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate7585627669875003657; Input/output error
     [[node save_2/SaveV2 (defined at <ipython-input-48-1ef727974922>:66) ]]
     [[node save_2/SaveV2 (defined at <ipython-input-48-1ef727974922>:66) ]]
```

I thought it could be due to diskspace but I have 332.38 GB available so that can't be it.

I'm not sure what other pieces would cause this but if any other details are needed, please ask and I'll update my post.

[Full Error]

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-48-1ef727974922>", line 66, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 832, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 844, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 881, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 510, in _build_internal
    save_tensor = self._AddSaveOps(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 210, in _AddSaveOps
    save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 124, in save_op
    tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1807, in save_v2
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Comment: Can u put traceback from above the error you posted here?

Comment: Added what I could!

Comment: What is your HW Accelerator in  `Runtime type` ? Based on tag `google-colab` I assume you run this on google colab.

Comment: You're correct. Its GPU,Python 3

Comment: Also getting this error with the latest (stable) release of TF 2.0 when using ModelCheckpoint callback

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a google drive api call quota problem as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55954485/google-colaboratory-oserror-errno-5-input-output-error)

I was facing this problem as well as i was unable to save the model
I worked around it by saving my model in the contents folder and then creating a zip file and then downloading it and manually upload

```
import shutil

def zip_model(keras_model, filename):
  modelpath = f'/content/{filename}'
  keras_model.save(modelpath)
  shutil.make_archive(modelpath, 'zip', modelpath)

# usage:
# zipmodel(keras_model, 'model')
```