# OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error when using Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, oserror

I was working just fine with Google Colaboratory and suddenly this error started to pop up each time I try to load any type of file. It first started when I was trying to read an hdf file, now everything won't open.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-65c4e8d1c435> in <module>()
----> 1 eo=EOPatch.load('./20.Clean_Textural_features/eopatch_0')
      2 eo

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/eolearn/core/eodata.py in load(path, features, lazy_loading, filesystem)
    530             path = '/'
    531 
--> 532         return load_eopatch(EOPatch(), filesystem, path, features=features, lazy_loading=lazy_loading)
    533 
    534     def time_series(self, ref_date=None, scale_time=1):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/eolearn/core/eodata_io.py in load_eopatch(eopatch, filesystem, patch_location, features, lazy_loading)
     76             loading_data = executor.map(lambda loader: loader.load(), loading_data)
     77 
---> 78     for (ftype, fname, _), value in zip(features, loading_data):
     79         eopatch[(ftype, fname)] = value
     80 

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result_iterator()
    584                     # Careful not to keep a reference to the popped future
    585                     if timeout is None:
--> 586                         yield fs.pop().result()
    587                     else:
    588                         yield fs.pop().result(end_time - time.monotonic())

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    423                 raise CancelledError()
    424             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 425                 return self.__get_result()
    426 
    427             self._condition.wait(timeout)

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py in run(self)
     54 
     55         try:
---> 56             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     57         except BaseException as exc:
     58             self.future.set_exception(exc)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/eolearn/core/eodata_io.py in <lambda>(loader)
     74     if not lazy_loading:
     75         with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
---> 76             loading_data = executor.map(lambda loader: loader.load(), loading_data)
     77 
     78     for (ftype, fname, _), value in zip(features, loading_data):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/eolearn/core/eodata_io.py in load(self)
    217                     return self._decode(gzip_fp, self.path)
    218 
--> 219             return self._decode(file_handle, self.path)
    220 
    221     def save(self, data, file_format, compress_level=0):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/eolearn/core/eodata_io.py in _decode(file, path)
    268 
    269         if FileFormat.NPY.extension() in path:
--> 270             return np.load(file)
    271 
    272         raise ValueError('Unsupported data type.')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    434         _ZIP_SUFFIX = b'PK\x05\x06' # empty zip files start with this
    435         N = len(format.MAGIC_PREFIX)
--> 436         magic = fid.read(N)
    437         # If the file size is less than N, we need to make sure not
    438         # to seek past the beginning of the file

OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Also some notebooks won't open and this appears instead:
[image]

I looked around at similar posts here, but didn't understand anything. Therefore, any help would be highly appreciated.

PS: my files are in subfolders and not directly contained in 'My Drive'. I have a lso disabled all the adblocks ad the problem persists...

Answer (score 0):

I think the file/link has been used for downloading beyond its weekly limit. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511015/6484844) may help you.
Some [discussion](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/2035857?hl=en) about Google's policy on hosting data on drive.

- The solution is to wait for couple of hours/days and try again.